# Method of choice for unconstrained saddle point problem? (numerical, FOMs)

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I have found out that Mirror Prox seems to be a good First Order Method for general case constrained saddle point problems. I was also able to find some references to so called "planar methods", though I am not quite sure what are they.

Would you recommend something? Does it make may sense to use Mirror Prox (or Mirror Descent in general) for unconstrained problems?

Comment: Some reference is needed for uncommon methods like this one, for example (http://sma.epfl.ch/~anchpcommon/students/Mazzurco_Master.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie ok, I would suggest https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4980 "Section 4.2 Mirror descent"

Comment: Thanks: very rich lecture notes